# setInterval function on ellipsis trimming paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I have a question on trimming paragraphs and adding ellipsis to the end of each trimmed paragraphs within isotope. The content from isotope. We are also using infinite scroll. The problem is that the ellipsis function works fine on the content that is already in the DOM on page load, but when new content is loaded from infinite scroll the ellipsis function will not work on the new paragraphs.

My solution is to use `setInterval` on the function to just run every second, which does the trick accept it keeps adding more dot dot dots to it each time it runs. What I would like to do is be able to empty the `...` each time the interval runs. At least I think this is an answer. I just don't know how to implement it. My code is below and any suggestions would be appreciated:

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () {
    trim();
}, 500);

function trim() {
    var MORE = "...";
    $(".gallery .spotProfile p.trim-ellipsis").each(function () {
        var $ths = $(this),
            txt = $ths.text();

        // Clear the text
        $ths.text("");

        // First 100 chars
        $ths.append( $("<span>").text( txt.substr(0, 80) ) );

        // The rest
        $ths.append( $("<span>").text( txt.substr(80, txt.length) ).hide() );

        // More link
        $ths.append(
        $("<a class=trimmed>").text(MORE).click(function () {
            var $ths = $(this);
            $ths.prev().hide();
            // more.empty();
            $ths.text(MORE);
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: Think of the steps involved to solve this problem, 1st thing is to find out if the paragraph has three dots, that's simple, just check if the text content ends with three dots or if it has the ellipsis class, this is really basic stuff. If it has either then skip on that paragraph...

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple.

```
$(".gallery .spotProfile p.trim-ellipsis").each(function(){
    var $ths = $(this),
        txt = $ths.text();

    if( $ths.find('.trimmed')[0] ) return;
```

Just check if the element has the trimmed element and return (continue next loop)